# Other Ideas for Clickable Graph Buildup

Tags: graphics

I am trying to show elements of a graph, their explanations, and further analysis of their explanations, but in a way that the user would click to see more, if the user wants. I have a crude example below using `Manipulate` and `Tooltip` but it has two drawbacks: (1) I am missing a layer of complexity, only showing two layers, the additional elements and their explanations, not the third element, analysis of the explanations; (2) the clicking is done at the control area, whereas I would prefer the clicking to happen on the graph itself.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Example of code:

```
Manipulate[Graphics[{
   Circle[],
   Line[{{0, -1}, {0, -5}}],
   Line[{{-2, -1.5}, {2, -1.5}}],
   Line[{{-1, -10}, {0, -5}, {1, -10}}],
   If[ShowHat == 1, 
    Tooltip[Disk[{-.3, .7}, {.7, .3}], "This is the hat!"]],
   If[ShowGlove == 1, 
    Tooltip[Rectangle[{1.9, -1.3}, {2.1, -1.6}], 
     "This is the glove! The glove can be blue."]]
   }],
 {ShowHat, {0, 1}}, {ShowGlove, {0, 1}}]
```

and this is the result, with the glove tooltip showing:

[image]

Comment: Take a look at `EventHandler`, you can also wrap graphics primitives with e.g. `Button`: `Button[Circle[], Print[1]]`. It is good that you provided a big picture but pleas add precise info what are you trying to achieve and where are you stuck, in order for that question to be answerable.

Comment: p.s. there is also a `ClickPane`.

Comment: How do you expect the user to access the 3rd level? Double clicking? Right Clicking? Some other way? Also, what form does the 3rd level take? Popup pane? Separate popup window? Please provide this information as an update to your question.

Comment: I am thinking that the first click in a particular area displays items (like the hat or glove in this example) a second click there shows text, and explanations are tooltips to the text.

Answer (score 3):

Using @Kuba's suggestion, one solution is to use nested `Dynamic@If` commands inside a `ClickPane`:

```
lefthand = {-2, -1.5};
righthand = {2, -1.5};
pubicbone = {0, -3};
leftfoot = {-1, -6};
rightfoot = {1, -6};
DynamicModule[{pt = {3, 0}}, ClickPane[Graphics[{
    White,
    Tooltip[Disk[], "Click on the head area to see the hat"],
    Black, Circle[],
    Line[{{0, -1}, pubicbone}],
    Line[{lefthand, righthand}],
    Line[{leftfoot, pubicbone, rightfoot}],
    Dynamic@If[pt \[Element] Disk[],
      {Tooltip[Disk[{-.3, .7}, {.7, .3}],"This is the hat! Click it for more."],
       Dynamic@If[pt \[Element] Disk[{-.3, .7}, {.7, .3}],
            {White, Tooltip[Text["Hat", {-.3, .7}], "Hat can be black or gray."]},
                Black]}, Black]
    }], (pt = #) &]]
```

This displays the person without the hat unless the user clicks on the face. Then, if the user clicks on the hat, it gets labeled and the label's tooltip has the additional information:

[image]

Any proposals for more elegant code would be most welcome.